# How can I swtich authorization method by ENV variable?

Tags: symfony, authentication, saml

I meet an unusual problem.
We have a **form_login** (based on FOS user-bundle). And now we want to change it to hslavich/OneloginSamlBundle for **saml** auth. But we want to save ability to select an auth method by changing environment vars in kubernetes deployment.
We use k8s on prod with pre-build images (implements "bin/console cache:warmup" in composer scripts for generating cache).

I'm implemented an environment variable for switch needed config.
Than I generate a switcher like this:

```
return static function (ContainerConfigurator $container) {
    $isSamlEnabled = getenv('IS_AUTH_SAML_ENABLE');
    if($isSamlEnabled === true) {
        $container->import('security_provider_configs/saml.yml');
    }
    else {
        $container->import('security_provider_configs/ldap.yml');
    }
};
```

But this solution use fixed variable IS_AUTH_SAML_ENABLE, which was is in builded image and can't be changed in kubernetes deployment.

We can add new APP_ENV stage, for difference prod-form and prod-saml, we can build two images like 'v2.123-form' and 'v2.123-saml'. But this will brake all CI/CD in our company. It's very difficult.

Do you know any methods to switch auth method by change env variable?

security.yml like this:

```yaml
security:
  providers:
    form_usr:
      id: my_service.provider.user
    saml_provider:
      entity:
        class: MyService\UserModel
        property: username

  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    main:
      pattern: ^/
      saml:
        provider: saml_provider
        user_factory: user_saml_factory
        username_attribute: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name
        persist_user: true
        check_path: /saml/acs
        login_path: /saml/login
      form_login:
        provider: form_usr
        default_target_path: about
        always_use_default_target_path: true
      logout:
        target: /login
      anonymous: true
```

Comment: Through using that closure, you build the container based on the environment that is used at that time. Later changes of that setting do not trigger a rebuild, so you cannot change that setting on runtime. Sadly, I can't come up with a better solution at this time

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not completely certain that this will work, but this case demands some testing on your part. ;o) Please report back if it indeed does work.

As Nico Haase correctly pointed out, your env vars are resolved at cache/compile-time. However, this is a poster case for `APP_ENV` (which is usually `dev` on dev systems and `prod` on production), you could add/use `prod_ldap` and `prod_saml` instead of just `prod`, which absolutely can have implications on your application. (switching a user from one to the other will not work without some hassle or at least re-login) - see https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/configuration/environments.html for some more information about adding more environments. The documentation is for symfony 4.1 so please don't blindly follow the examples. Stuff has changed, but the general idea should still be viable.

For that to work, you would have to adapt config/bundles.php, and possibly src/Kernel.php and maybe even more things, and you probably have to copy some of the env-specific configs ...

Since all caching and container-building is done depending on APP_ENV and the results are written to a APP_ENV-specific cache location, the containers as well as the caches and sessions would reside in different locations - you'd have the same code base and the same project directory but different cache and config dirs. Unless your application is extremely sophisticated and sensitive to this, this should work.

Please note, that depending on how you're changing your APP_ENV, this might absolutely not work. If it's set by the webserver, I'm confident it *should*.
Please also note, that to put your system live, you will have to do both `bin/console cache:clear --env=prod_saml` as well as `bin/console cache:clear --env=prod_ldap`, composer will run the one in .env(.local) automatically - if you even run composer - but you only can have one at the time. You could extend the composer.json to run both cache:clear commands as a post-*something* script.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jakumi for an answer! But this solution have some troubles in our CI/CD.

I solved my problem. It takes to add a private parameter to Kernel:

```
final class Kernel extends SymfonyKernel
{
...

    private $cacheSuffix = '';
```

and fill it in constructor:

```
    public function __construct(string $environment, bool $debug)
    {
        parent::__construct($environment, $debug);

        $useSaml = getenv('SAML_ENABLE') === 'true';
        $this->cacheSuffix =  $useSaml ? '/saml' : '';
    }
```

After that we need to replace Kernel->getCacheDir by custom:

```
    public function getCacheDir(): string
    {
        return $this->getProjectDir() . '/var/cache/' . $this->getEnvironment() . $this->cacheSuffix;
    }
```

So, we can to warmup cache for both auth methods, for example in composer.json:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": [
        "export SAML_ENABLE=false && bin/console cache:warmup",
        "export SAML_ENABLE=true && bin/console cache:warmup"
    ],
...
```